# How to convert a char to unicode value in f#

Tags: .net, unicode, f#, char

I made a simple ceasar cipher in javascript and I need to make it again in f#. I used the charCodeAt() method in javascript to convert individual characters in a string into their unicode value. does anyone know how to do this in F# or if there is a similar command to charCodeAt? I've ben searching for hours and I'm running out of time.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a char, then just convert it to an integer:

```
> int 'a';;
val it : int = 97
```

If you have a string, combine this with the indexer:

```
> int ("xyza".[3]);;
val it : int = 97
```

Answer (score 7):

To handle code points outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, I believe you'll want to use `System.Char.ConvertToUtf32`, e.g.

```
let input = "\uD800\uDC00\u0061\u0300\u00C6"
System.Char.ConvertToUtf32(input, 0) //gives 65536, which is good
int input.[0] //gives 55296, not what you want
```

To use this effectively, you'll need to combine this with help from `System.Globalization.StringInfo`, otherwise, for example, you'll get an exception if you try `System.Char.ConvertToUtf32(input, 1)` in the example above. Something like,

```
open System.Globalization
let si = StringInfo(input)
let teArr = Array.init si.LengthInTextElements (fun i -> si.SubstringByTextElements(i,1))

System.Char.ConvertToUtf32(teArr.[0], 0) //65536
System.Char.ConvertToUtf32(teArr.[1], 0) //97
System.Char.ConvertToUtf32(teArr.[2], 0) //198
```